# NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 6]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I am developing IOS App.in my application when i run app. App Run perfect. But Array length not count in For each. How to Count Array length in for each. Thanks in Advance.

This is the error..

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 6]'
```

Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    count = 0;
    marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = camera.target;
    marker.snippet = @"Jalandhar";
    marker.map = mapView;
    self.view = mapView;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLocation:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateLocation:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [mapView clear];

    NSMutableArray *longitute = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *latLongDict = @{@"lat": @[@"31.3062", @"31.3107",@"31.3102",@"31.3194",@"31.3312",@"29.9083",@"31.2941",],@"long": @[@"75.5935", @"75.6061",@"75.6117",@"75.5845",@"75.5908",@"75.7299",@"75.5844",]};
    [longitute addObject:latLongDict];

    for (NSDictionary *dic in longitute) {
        NSString *val = [[dic valueForKey:@"lat"]objectAtIndex:count];
        NSString *value = [[dic valueForKey:@"long"]objectAtIndex:count];
        NSLog(@"%@",val);
        NSLog(@"%@",value);
        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2.0] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
        center.latitude=[val doubleValue];
        center.longitude=[value doubleValue];
        marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = center;
        marker.map = mapView;
        self.view = mapView;
        [CATransaction commit];
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the final code or part of the code in exception?

Comment: Each time your timer fires you increment `count` and you don't stop the timer or reset `count` when it exceed the size of your arrays

Answer (score 0):

The timer that invokes `updateLocation` method has set `repeats:YES` so it will be called every 2 seconds.

You are incrementing the count `count++;` in for loop in `updateLocation` method. However, you reset the count only once in `viewDidLoad`. So the first invocation will run just fine, but the next one will fail with index out of bounds.

Add `count = 0;` below `[map clear]` in `updateLocation` method to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Reset the `count` to 0 just before the `foreach` loop so your code will be like this:

```
count = 0 // Reset count to zero before the foreach loop
for (NSDictionary *dic in longitute) {
        NSString *val = [[dic valueForKey:@"lat"]objectAtIndex:count];
        NSString *value = [[dic valueForKey:@"long"]objectAtIndex:count];
        NSLog(@"%@",val);
        NSLog(@"%@",value);
        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2.0] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
        center.latitude=[val doubleValue];
        center.longitude=[value doubleValue];
        marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = center;
        marker.map = mapView;
        self.view = mapView;
        [CATransaction commit];
        count++;
}
```